# Stop storyboard that begin in visual state

Tags: wpf, triggers, storyboard, datatrigger

I have a storyboard begins by state:

```
<VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
    <VisualStateGroup x:Name="MySG">
        <VisualState x:Name="State1">
            <Storyboard>
                <BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Btn1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.IsEnabled)">
                    <DiscreteBooleanKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="True"/>
                </BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            </Storyboard>
        </VisualState>
        <VisualState x:Name="State2">
            <Storyboard>
                <BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Btn1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.IsEnabled)">
                    <DiscreteBooleanKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="False"/>
                </BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            </Storyboard>
        </VisualState>
    </VisualStateGroup>
</VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
```

I want to stop it by trigger in the button:

```
  <Button x:Name="Btn1"  Height="50" Width="200" Content="My Button">
            <Button.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=txt1,Path=(Validation.HasError)}" Value="True">
                    <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                        <StopStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="?"/>
                    </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                    <DataTrigger.ExitActions>
                        <ResumeStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="?"/>
                    </DataTrigger.ExitActions>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Button.Triggers>
        </Button>
```

**How can I do that if I dont know the `BeginStoryboardName`?**

Comment: If your using VSM, why not just use something like `GoToStateAction` and apply that from your `Trigger` when needed accordingly.

Comment: @Viv. It's more complicated than presented here. I also need the state and the storyboard when I have error. I just wanted to know if there is a way to stop the storyboards that are in the state when I run the storyboard from the error.